# vmWare Workstation External Accessibility Issue

Tags: windows, centos7, portforwarding, vmware-workstation, gitlab-omnibus

I'm running Windows Server 2012 w/ vmWare Workstation.  I've built a GitLab VM on Centos 7 that's totally setup and accessible on my local network. It's configured using Bridged Mode so it has it's own IP from the DHCP Server.

I use No-IP to connect to my Network externally which has been working great for several years now. I have port-forwarding setup within my router to forward traffic for the GitLab webUI to the GitLab VM, but it's not accessible externally. I even tried setting up the port forwarding to direct the traffic to the Windows Server and then setup internal port forwarding w/ netsh on the Windows Server to forward the traffic to the GitLab VM, making sure I opened the port on the Windows Firewall (even tried disabling it), but I still can't get to the GitLab VM externally. AFAIK running a VM w/ a Bridged adapter should essentially be like it is just another physical machine on the network.

Now, I am running IIS on the Windows Server, but when I specify a specific port using my public No-IP Domain, the router should detect the traffic on that port and forward it according to the rules that I have setup, correct? IIS shouldn't be interfering with any traffic on other ports with the external Domain.

I'm totally stumped on this on and searching around the web really hasn't helped much.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that I did everything 100% correctly with setting up port forwarding right to the IP of the VM, but my workplace blocks just about every port except for 80 and 443. Tested connectivity from an AWS box and everything is accessible exactly as designed.

Now I just feel like an idiot, but hey, I figured it out.